# QIWI API. Получаем баланс в Гугл таблицу

Tags: json

Пытаюсь получить в гугл таблице баланс кошелька Киви. Делаю через Apps Script.

```
function bankbalans() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Прайс");
  var row = sheet.getRange(2,2);

  var options = {
    method: "GET" ,
    headers: {
    "Bearer" : "6d42cc2caf5da45d19d54bf37f3e7ea"
   }
   }
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://edge.qiwi.com/funding-sources/v2/persons/79173824745/accounts",options);
Logger.log (response)


}
```

Получаю в ответ ошибку. Токен и номер правильный. Почему не могу получить авторизацию?

```
Exception: Request failed for https://edge.qiwi.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"serviceName":"funding-sources","errorCode":"auth.unauthorized","description":"Unauthorized access","userMessage":"Unauthorized access","dateTime"... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

https://developer.qiwi.com/en/qiwi-wallet-personal/#balance

Answer (score 0):

Вы неверно добавляете заголовок. В документации явно написано:

> Итоговый заголовок, добавляемый в каждый запрос к API QIWI Кошелька:
>
> Authorization: Bearer U1QtOTkwMTAyLWNud3FpdWhmbzg3M

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно прописать. Пытаюсь так, но не работает. headers: {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer, 6d42cc2caf5da45d19d54bf37f3e7ef9"
   }

Comment: Так я Вам в ответе написал как правильно, запятых в запросе нет. Попробовал со своим кошельком - все работает. Перевыпустите токен и проставьте все галочки в разрешениях если не получится.